# React-typescript chart.js error 'type' is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, types, react-chartjs

i am a learning typescript, recently moved from react, i am using chart js for some graph in my react-typescript project and from few hours i am getting this error

`Property 'type' is missing in type '{ data: { labels: string[]; datasets: { label: string; data: number[]; fill: boolean; backgroundColor: string; borderColor: string; }[]; }; options: { scales: { yAxes: { ticks: { beginAtZero: boolean; }; }[]; }; }; }' but required in type 'Props'` 
[image]

it would be great if anyone could help me out here
THank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though *react-chartjs-2* is not expecting an type props for Line component and its value is assign to *line* by default, The interface used has the type props as required. Please find the interface [here](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/67cd5622d702230f1aa5e06d994134fdd451bd7b/src/types.ts#L4)

Please pass the type prop to the link tag.

```
<line type='line' data={data} />
```

Comment: Hey akhil, thank you so much man, u really are a life saviour

Comment: hi  @Akshay98 , how does this work for doughnut?
`<Doughnut  options={options} data={data} type="doughnut" />` Fails with the same error as OP

Comment: Try disabling Typescript for that line and check